# method not waiting until running again

Tags: ios, swift

I have a delegate method that is called multiple times from a framework and I need it to wait to display all letters before it is ran again. I have tried `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`, but another instance of the method runs when it is called again.

```
  var myInt = 1

            for letter in message.characters {

                let delay = 0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * Double(myInt)
                let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

                dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.textView.text = self.textView.text + String(letter)
                })

                myInt = myInt + 1
            }
            self.textView.text = self.textView.text + "\n"
```

Comment: use flag, do not run method again until all letters are not displayed

Comment: when you use dispatch_after<main_queue> you are not blocking main queue as you may think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a `serial` queue

```
let delegateQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.domain.delegateQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

in the delegate method

```
dispatch_async(delegateQueue, ^{
    //all the things done in delegate method
})
```

Comment: this is what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make two threads like below and then run code.. the task you want to done first and the task you need to wait can be managed like below :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {() -> Void in
            // waiting task

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in

      // task you have to do first
  })
        })
```

still any query you can ask me..

Comment: I added my code in this and I am still running into the same problem:

Comment: I put my code in the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue section